# have only selected properties of objects from an array of objects using jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of objects for ex.

```
var input = [
  {title: 'one', code: '1', desc: 'sds'},
  {title: 'two', code: '2', desc: 'wewe'},
  {title: 'three', code: '3', desc: 'dsf'}
];
```

I have an array of required properties say

```
var required = ['title', 'desc'];
```

and my required output (based on input and required arrays) is

```
var output = [
      {title: 'one', desc: 'sds'},
      {title: 'two', desc: 'wewe'},
      {title: 'three', desc: 'dsf'}
    ];
```

How this can be done in jquery, yeah of-course  I can do this using `$.each` and then checking for each object property.

but can it be done using `$.map` or `$.grep` or any other method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `Array.map` for this, no need of jQuery

```
var output = input.map(function(obj){
   var rtn = {};
   for(var i = 0; i < required.length; i++)
      rtn[required[i]] = obj[required[i]]; // set the required properties
   return rtn; // return it
});
```